# dynamically create columns in pyspark sql select statement

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe called unique_attributes.  the dataframe has columns productname, productbrand, producttype, weight, id.  I am partitioning by some columns and trying to get the first value of the id column using a window function.  I would like to be able to dynamically pass a list of columns to partition by.  so for example if I wanted to add the weight column to the partition without having to code another 'col('weight') in the select, just instead pass a list.  does anyone have a suggestion how to accomplish this?  I have an example below.

current code:

```
w2 = Window().partitionBy(['productname', 
                                  'productbrand', 
                                  'producttype']).orderBy(unique_attributes.id.asc())

first_item_id_df=unique_attributes\
.select(col('productname'),
        col('productbrand'),
        col('producttype')),first("id",True).over(w2).alias('matchid')).distinct()
```

desired dynamic code:

```
column_list=['productname', 
             'productbrand', 
             'producttype',
             'weight']

w2 = Window().partitionBy(column_list).orderBy(unique_attributes.id.asc())

# somehow creates

first_item_id_df=unique_attributes\
.select(col('productname'),
        col('productbrand'),
        col('producttype'), col('weight'),first("id",True).over(w2).alias('matchid')).distinct()
```

Comment: Just use `*column_list`

Comment: @mck thank you for getting back to me so quickly, do you mean like this:  first_item_id_df=unique_attributes\
.select(*column_list,first("id",True).over(w2).alias('matchid')).distinct()